# How to quantify the differences of two matrices with different dimension in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am new in using matlab. I have 7 matrices that I have to compare and quantify the similarity among them. I have used Corrx and I have tried corrCoeff and some other methods. Since they have different dimensions , I have limit choices.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: What do your matrices represent? Some specific examples would help. Also, what should "similar" mean? Different types of correlations will quantify different ideas of similarity.

Comment: They represents Neuron's plot. I have 3 images of one neuron and I want to measure how much they are similar to each other.